# Depth of bounded fan-in circuits for unbounded fan-in circuits

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, circuit-complexity, circuit-depth

Assume that we have an unbounded fan-in circuit family of depth $d(n)$ and size $s(n)$.

What is *the smallest depth* (in terms of $d(n)$ and $n$ and $s(n)$) bounded fan-in circuit family of size $poly(s)$ for it?

In particular what is the largest depth $d(n)$ for which we know polynomial size unbounded fan-in circuit families of depth $d(n)$ are in $\mathsf{NC^1}$?

Comment: Is there any example of a family of circuits for which $d(n) = \omega(1), s(n) = n^{O(1)}$ but no equivalent $\mathsf{AC}^0$ family is known. Yet the computed family of functions is in $\mathsf{NC}^1$.

Comment: @SamiD, I don't know any natural example, for artificial one we can take a suitable variant of circuit evaluation problem, e.g. circuit evaluation for $AC$ circuits of depth $\lg \lg n$.

Comment: ps: since the time I have posted the question I have asked a few experts in circuit complexity and the question seems to be open.

Comment: I thought that class or even its uniform iterated version $\mathsf{FOLL}$ is not known to be comparable even to Logspace (see e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000001917647)

Comment: Thanks @SamiD for the reference. It seems the problem is open even for smaller depths e.g. $\lg^*n$.

Comment: I guess that is true though I cannot recall where (if anywhere) this is explicitly mentioned as an open question...